# Using Rank2 polymorphic functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to write a function like this

```
inTransform tr f = tr . f . tr
```

but I have troubles to type it correctly.

I tried to use Rank2 existential types like

```
inTransform :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
```

But when I try to use it, for example in

```
inTransform reverse id [1, 6]
```

I have strange errors like

```
Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘[a0]’
      Expected: a1 -> a1
        Actual: [a0] -> [a0]
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall a1. a1 -> a1
```

So maybe existential types are not the right solution ?

-- Edit --

Ok so as suggested the proposed type

```
inTransform :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> a -> b
```

but actually not for may use case which is more complex, like:

```
 inTransform reverse (:[]) [1, 6]
```

The problem is that the `tr` function is of type `a -> a`, but maybe not the same a when applied after.
This is why I was thinking to apply existential Rank2 types

Comment: GHCi `:t inTransform` tells me `inTransform :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> a -> b` as the type. Of course you could force `a = b` like you tried, but I don't see a point in doing so.

Comment: This works for my first exemple, but actually my use case is more complex, I updated the question

Comment: Your example is invalid `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` so the second argument to `:` has to be a list, not a single value like `1`, you either meant `(1:)` or `(++[1])`

Comment: For the posted examples `inTransform :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` should work. I can't see how to generalize it further.

Comment: @cafce25 or `(:[[1]])`, which would better match the context.

Comment: Yes sorry ` inTransform reverse (:[]) [1, 6]`.

Using
`inTransform :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a`

Does not work since `(:[])` is not `a -> a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-} -- ← should always be enabled
```

Whilst your rank-2 type does the job of allowing the transformation to be used in different-type contexts, the type `∀ a. a -> a` is too strong to be able to use this with any nontrivial transformation.

For your specific example, it would work to restrict it to lists:

```
inTransform :: (∀ a. [a] -> [a]) -> ([b] -> [c]) -> ([b] -> [c])

> inTransform reverse (map realToFrac) [1,2,3]
[1.0,2.0,3.0]
```

But you may find that this is too specific to warrant the abstraction.

A compromise is to pick an arbitrary type constructor that the function is universally quantified over, but keep it rank-2 in the type argument to this constructor:

```
inTransform :: ∀ f b c. (∀ a. f a -> f a) -> (f b -> f c) -> (f b -> f c)
```

This works just as well for reversing lists, but can also be used for other use cases with self-inverse polymorphic functions as long as the polymorphic argument and result share an outer shape.

Comment: The last type signature that quantifies over `f` won't work as is, because it also needs to quantify over `b` and `c`. Also, I'd replace the unicode symbol with the full `forall` keyword to avoid having to enable the `UnicodeSyntax` extension.

Comment: @Noughtmare 1. right; 2. wrong ...

Comment: but then how can I implement the function ?
doing
`inTransform tr fct = tr . fct . tr`

doesn't compile

Comment: @louis my mistake, the arguments need to be listified too.

Comment: Just a subsidiary question, so as I understand it is impossible to write such a function so it works both on `a, [a], [[a]]` ?

What is don't really get is this: "is too strong to be able to use this with any nontrivial transformation"

Comment: @louis you can get it to work on `a` by using [`Identity a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity) and on `[[a]]` by using a `newtype L2 a=L2 [[a]]`.